# Angularjs: modal window to be with the size of the window - the angular way

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angular. I have done this before with jquery. I wonder what is the angular way to to this. Also is it possible this functionality to be wrapped in service or directive so it can be reused with other widgets.

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div my-modal="{ data: 'test2'}">test2</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'myModal']);

angular.module("myModal", []).directive("myModal", function ($modal) {
    "use strict";
    return {
      template: '<div ng-click="clickMe(rowData)" ng-transclude></div>',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        rowData: '&myModal' 
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.clickMe = function () {
            $modal.open({
            template: "<div style=\"overflow:auto\">Created By:" + scope.rowData().data + "</div>"
                        + "<div class=\"modal-footer\">"
                        + "<button class=\"btn btn-primary\" ng-click=\"ok()\">OK</button>"
                        + "<button class=\"btn btn-warning\" ng-click=\"cancel()\">Cancel</button>"
                        + "</div>",
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.ok = function () {
                    $modalInstance.close({ test: "test"});
                };

                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            }
        });
        }
      }
    };
});
```

Working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/yzxtWwZQdq94Tagdiswa?p=preview

I am very new to angular. Any working example will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`$modal` uses Bootstrap modals and those have `@media-queries` set on `.modal-dialog` CSS class - you have to override that to make modal stretch to `window` width